# How do I test associations in models with RSpec in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to Rails 5, and trying to test an extremely simple database model, but I can't seem to get it right. I'm trying to test the `has_many` association.

The model code looks like this:

`app/models/database_models/response.rb`

```
module DatabaseModels
  class Response < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :question_responses, :class_name => 'DatabaseModels::
QuestionResponse'

  end
end
```

The spec (RSpec) looks like this

`spec/models/screener_response_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe DatabaseModels::Response, type: :model do
  it { is_expected.to have_many(:question_responses) }
end
```

It fails with:

`` expected #<DatabaseModels::Response:0x007fd91ccda210> to respond to `has_many?` ``

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you include the shoulda gem? As far as I know only this gem provides the matcher you are using.

Comment: I do have `gem 'shoulda-matchers'` in my :test group in my Gemfile.

Comment: There is an open Rails 5 PR https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/pull/960 . I think this gem is not Rails 5 ready.

Comment: is there another way I can test this using RSpec without `shoulda_matchers`

Comment: `expect(described_class.reflect_on_association(:question_responses).macro).to eq :has_many` should work with Rails 5 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to test this would be to test the actual behaviour:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe DatabaseModels::Response, type: :model do

  let(:response) { described_class.new }
  it 'has many question responses' do
    expect( response.question_responses.new ).to be_a_new DatabaseModels::
QuestionResponse 
  end
end
```

Otherwise you can use reflection which is basically what `shoulda` does:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe DatabaseModels::Response, type: :model do
  it 'has many question responses' do
    relation = described_class.reflect_on_association(:question_resp‌​onses)
    expect(relation.macro).to eq :has_many
  end
end
```

Comment: However I recently used shoulda-matchers in a Rails 5 app to test a `has_many` relationship and it worked without a hitch - are you sure you remembered to save the changes in the model file?

Comment: I definitely did save. Perhaps there's something slightly off in my syntax but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Hmm what happens if you do `it should have_many(:question_responses).class_name('DatabaseModels::QuestionResponse')`? On a side note I do believe  you can drop the class name option here as both classes have the same module nesting.